# Support Vector Machine using previous predictions

Tags: machine-learning, svm, prediction

My svm gets as input a list of values and predicts a label for each entry. The list is processed from front to back.

Now my question is whether there is the possibility to consider previous predictions. Because each label may be awarded only once.

If a label has been awarded, it may not be awarded a second time.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds to be a sequence model. You can use CRF for that.